# Designing a eCommerce Gifting Experience

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, e-commerce

I am currently working on an artisan food eCommerce site,

One product in particular they offer are a kind of Product Basket subscription in which you receive several products per month.

I am trying to make the Gifting process of this product as seamless as possible, for both the purchaser and the gift receiver.

The current gifting method is nothing out of the standard eCommerce process, someone buys the subscription on their account, adds in the recipients details in the delivery fields. Done. - Of course this presents issue then if the recipient wants to make any kind of changes.

**Now to my proposed solutions**

I am debating how the recipients process should flow in particular.

They receive an Email with a gift code, the email contains instructions, should they :

*- Get sent to the Product page and add it to the Basket themselves and continue the process as normal?* - This presents a possible issue that they add a Size option that is out of the price range of their Gift code.

*- Get sent to the Homepage, but with the specific Product already added to the Basket so they can continue seamlessly into the checkout process.* - It would have to made clear that the Item was indeed in the basket, perhaps by having the mini-shopping cart open with the product inside when arriving from this link.

*- Get sent directly to the Basket page with the Product already in the basket so the only next step is to proceed to checkout.* - This seems like a sensible solution but not sure of the User experience in terms of receiving a Gift code, clicking a link and immediately arriving on a Basket / Cart page.

Any suggestions or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: I'll add that I am open to non-gift code related solutions as I am not even sure if this is the best way forward.

Comment: The last one is the option I'd want as a user. I want the fewest possible steps between receive and accept, except maybe customizing if possible.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you want to implement the gift itself, and what is the main goal you want to achieve.

Probably the simplest use case is when the recipient will take the gift as is without any changes, and in this case the fastest solution is for the gift to work like a product but the cost is $0.00. That way they can make a purchase as a guest without providing any further details.

The alternate use case is when the recipient will use the gift like a coupon, so you are applying a discount to an item such that any variations to the item will attract some additional cost. If you want to upsell to the potential customer then you can also encourage them to go through a browse process and purchase other items along with the gift.

I would think about how you normally want to achieve with the gifting process, and whether it is about incentivizing your current customers, or if you want to attract and upselling to potential customers. You should also consider the items in your inventory and whether you need to provide multiple ways to package a product into a gift item, or if the coupon idea works better.